# What does 'x' mark on the icons in package explorer in eclipse mean?

Tags: eclipse, icons, subclipse

I am not able to figure out what it means. I want to make sure if I should delete that package or not.

Also, what does revision number '-1' mean?

[image: I have attached a screenshot of the 'x' mark]

Comment: Look in the Problems view for more detailed messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "x" means that the folder is Scheduled for deletion.  If you ran svn status you would see this.  Likewise, if you did Team > Commit you would see these items in the dialog and if you committed, it would delete the folders from the repository.

Normally something that is Scheduled for deletion does not exist in the working copy, so you cannot see these indicators.  Obviously something on your end has put the items back.

You might want to run Team > Revert to remove the scheduled deletion.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I'm running an external Ant build script. It should be the case here. Your answer helped me understand what it really means.